# Using useEffect hook when unmounting with dynamic props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Struggling with hooks here.

I have the following code inside a component:

```
  const {isLoading, abortRequest} = props;

  const cleanUp = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (isLoading) abortRequest();
  }, [isLoading, abortRequest]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      cleanUp();
    };
  }, []);
```

I'm basically attempting to abort an AJAX request when the component unmounts, and the cancellation must only happen when the prop `isloading` is set to true (*initially it's set to false and turns to true when the request is first made*). The problem is that I'm getting a stale value for `props.isLoading` every time and therefore when the component unmounts it never aborts the request. I've tried to include the cleanUp function as a dependency for the `useEffect` hooks but that makes it run every time the cleanUp callback updates which is not what I want.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed

You simply do not require to use `useCallback` hook:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (isLoading) abortRequest();
    };
  }, [isLoading]);
```